# PHP - SQL query containing unicode is returning NULL for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, null

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT trans FROM `dictionary` WHERE `word` LIKE 'Çiçek'
```

like this (relevant code):

```
function gettranslation($word){
    return $this->query("SELECT trans FROM `dictionary` WHERE `word` LIKE '$word'");
}
function query($query){
    $result=mysqli_query($this->conn, "set character_set_results='utf8'");
    $result=mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    return $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
}
```

My mySQL table is made like this:

```
Word  | Trans
-------------
Flower| Çiçek
-------------
Çiçek | Flower
```

When the `$word` I pass to the `gettranslation` function is `Flower`, the result is `Çiçek`. However when I do the reverse, the result is `NULL`.

Also if I do `var_dump` on it, I get nothing. Not even an empty array.

Strangely enough, when I run the same query in PHPmyAdmin it runs fine.

Help?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you are risking sql injections, since you do not use the mysqli extension together with "prepared statements". This issue _might_ be an effect of that. Apart from that you should check the encoding setting of all components: php, mysql connection, table creation, ...

Comment: Which MySQL and PHP version is it ?

Comment: @arkascha It's on a local system for now. I will secure it properly later.

Comment: @jaycp Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.43
PHP extension: mysqli (Taken from PHPmyAdmin)

Comment: That approach is pretty risky, since you probably will _not_ secure it before taking it "online". :-) Why not code it right now? It is not more effort.

Comment: @arkascha Because this way is more simple. As in it's easier to troubleshoot and stuff like that. Then when everything is working nicely I will take security precautions. In any case if I only allow SELECT statements, since no passwords are stored in the database, that's already quite decent security. What will the attacker get? Words?

Comment: There shall in that time be rumors, of things going astray. And there shall be a great confusion as to where things really are.
And nobody will really know where lieth those little things that have attachments to other things.

Comment: We are talking about sql injection here. That is a thread to your operating system, not only to the data in your database. But just as you like. I just mention it, since it is against all best practices. But it certainly is your project and your time :-)

Comment: @arkascha Yes, my project, my time and I like doing one thing at a time and the current issue is getting nowhere from this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, `mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");` was required, like this:

```
function gettranslation($word){
    return $this->query("SELECT trans FROM `dictionary` WHERE `word` LIKE '$word'");
}
function query($query){
    //$result=mysqli_query($this->conn, "set character_set_results='utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result=mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    return $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=mysqli_query($this->conn, "set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

This only affects the character set used for returned strings, not the character set for incoming queries. So your query is interpreted as if it were ISO-8859-1-encoded: `LIKE 'ÃiÃ§ek'`. This doesn't match any data in the table.

Instead, set the character set for the whole connection:

```
$this->conn->set_charset('utf-8');
```

It's better to do this once when you connect, rather than on every query.

(**Never use `SET NAMES`.** This sets the connection encoding for MySQL without letting PHP's mysqli know that the encoding has changed, so when it comes to `mysqli_real_escape_string` some content it will use the wrong encoding. If the encoding in question is an East Asian multibyte encoding that means you get an SQL injection hole.)